# Process JSON data with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Can anyone please tell me how I can access this JSON data with JavaScript? I tried it wit the `$.each` loop, tried accessing with `[0]` but everything returned `undefined`.

JSON data from controller:

```
{
    "workers": {
        "107": "Lisa",
        "96": "Marvin",
        "24": "Michael",
        "23": "Patrick",
        "116": "Peter"
    }
}
```

Ajax Call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/cake/workers/getWorkersAsJSON.json',
    async: true,
    success: function(data) {
        // process
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `dataType: 'json'`

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/cake/workers/getWorkersAsJSON.json',
    async: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
       $.each(data.workers, function(i, v) {
          console.log(i + ' : ' + v);
       })
    }
});
```

Specifying the datatype as JSON will then convert it to a JavaScript object and you can iterate through it with `$.each` or call out items directly by using a `.` as a separator. The example above works.

*FYI: you don't need to specify `async: true` because it's true by default.*

Comment: I already specify the JSON extension when I call the method of the controller. Both is not necessary. Your solution worked, thanks for that! I am accepting it now!

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a jQuery short-hand of the `$.ajax datatype:json`. The function is called `getJSON`

In your example, it would be implemented like this:

```
$.getJSON( "/cake/workers/getWorkersAsJSON.json", function( data ) {
 console.log(data);
});
```

That would get the JSON, and the proceed to log the retrieved data as an array into Console.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Answer (score 1):

Hi please check the below code. You are sending object so have to access data using keys.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/cake/workers/getWorkersAsJSON.json',
    async: true,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data.workers.107) // should show "Lisa"
        //if you need to use loop, try these
        var keys = Object.keys(data.workers);

        for(var key in keys){ 
          console.log(data.workers[key]);  
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sohel but this still showed `undefined` in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
```

in your `success` function.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't looks like an array so not sure it could be processed with 'each' loop (please see JSON array definition here).
Most probably it would be accessible as

```
data.workers.107
```

If not simplest way to understand structure is to set breakpoint in ajax callback and check structure of JavaScript object.

Comment: This seems like the correct solution, if your server side is serving it with content type JSON, it should be automatically deserialized into data object as a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

Using the open source project [jinqJs](http://www.jinqJs.com)

You could make a sync call like this to get the JSON object:

```
var result = jinqJs().from('/cake/workers/getWorkersAsJSON.json').select();
```

an async way to access it:

```
var result;
    jinqJs().from('/cake/workers/getWorkersAsJSON.json', function(self) {
         result = self.select();
});
```

Comment: If he's already using jQuery, what would the benefits of using jinqJs be?

Comment: Because he can then make further LINQ expressions on it, like, groupBy(), .where(), etc...

Comment: Why would somebody not using .net care to use linq... Lol

Comment: The same reason why people use lodash and _underscore.